Downloading files from url that return save dialog box
I have trying download files form a url that return save dialog box. I am using wget. It is not working!
I am using the follow command
wget -ci LinkDownloadHw.csv
Bellow are a sample of links used in LinkDownloadHw.csv. It is pluviometer datas of Hidroweb, a plataform of National Water Agency in Brazil.

"http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/convencionais?tipo=3&documentos=2244030"
"http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/convencionais?tipo=3&documentos=2244054"
"http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/convencionais?tipo=3&documentos=2244088"
"http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/convencionais?tipo=3&documentos=2244090"

It returned messages of Invalid URL and Scheme Missing.
So, I have two question. First, How can I download files form url that return save dialog box? I accept other tools besides wget.
Second, Considering wget, how save files using different names as like as the last seven numbers in url?
Thanks for any help!

When reading the list of URLs to work with using wget -i, the URLs should not be quoted in the file.
Therefore, remove the double quotes at the start and end of each line in your input file.
You may do this with sed if you wish:
sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' LinkDownloadHw.csv >links.in

Then use the new file links.in with wget.
